# Loading several npz files in a multithreadedly

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I have several `.npz` files. All `.npz` file the same structures: each of them just contain two variables, always with the same variable names. As of now, I simply loop over all `.npz` files, retrieve the two variable values and append them into some global variable:

```
# Let's assume there are 100 npz files
x_train = []
y_train = []
for npz_file_number in range(100):
    data = dict(np.load('{0:04d}.npz'.format(npz_file_number)))
    x_train.append(data['x'])
    y_train.append(data['y'])
```

It takes a while, and the bottleneck is the CPU. The order in which `x` and `y` variables are appended to the `x_train` and `y_train` variables does not matter.

Is there any way to load several `.npz` files in a multithreadedly?

Comment: Sure, but the CPU will still be the bottleneck.  Adding more chefs to a kitchen doesn't speed up the food preparation.

Comment: @BrentWashburne Why wouldn't it help reducing the loading time?

Comment: Your code is trying to update two arrays from multiple threads.  How would this happen?  Each thread would be blocked while one thread updates the array, and then the next one would write to the array, and so on.  That is, only one thread would be active because of the shared lock.  Let me ask the same question: why do you think multiple threads would reduce loading time?

Comment: @BrentWashburne I think multiple threads would reduce loading time because the bottleneck is loading npz files, not appending.

Comment: To continue the kitchen analogy, each chef can prepare food independently, but they need to share the oven.  That is, each thread can read a file independently, but they need to share the arrays.  That's the bottleneck.  How would those threads append to the arrays simultaneously?

Comment: @BrentWashburne Maybe using different parts of the oven?

Comment: If you can do that with a CPU, there are some very big software companies that would like to know how you did it.  :-)  I'll leave the discussion now.

Comment: @BrentWashburne, I don't think your analogy is good here. If you have CPU bound code and there is a way to parallelize, then you should always be able to make things faster. If you can get faster in the language you are trying to use is a completely different story. In general: More chefs always speed up the food preparation, unless either only one of them can work at a time or they are tripping over their own feet :)

Comment: When loading compressed NPZ the loading procedure is most likely CPU-bound. On my system, the decompression implementation only utilizes a single CPU. Thus, we should see a significant improvement by distributing `np.load` calls across multiple threads (unless the implementation is holding on to the GIL). And indeed, I'm seeing a 3.3x speedup by scheduling multiple loads to a thread pool of 4 (4 core CPU, not counting hyper cores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised by the comments of @Brent Washburne and decided to try it out myself. I think the general problem is two-fold:

Firstly, reading data is often IO bound, so writing multi-threaded code often does not yield high performance gains. Secondly, doing shared memory parallelization in python is inherently difficult due to the design of the language itself. There's much more overhead compared to native c.

But let's see what we can do.

```
# some imports
import numpy as np
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

# creating some temporary data
tmp_dir = os.path.join('tmp', 'nptest')
if not os.path.exists(tmp_dir):
    os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
    for i in range(100):
        x = np.random.rand(10000, 50)
        file_path = os.path.join(tmp_dir, '%05d.npz' % i)
        np.savez_compressed(file_path, x=x)

def read_x(path):
    with np.load(path) as data:
        return data["x"]

def serial_read(files):
    x_list = list(map(read_x, files))
    return x_list

def parallel_read(files):
    with Pool() as pool:
        x_list = pool.map(read_x, files)
    return x_list
```

Okay, enough stuff prepared. Let's get the timings.

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dir, '*.npz'))

%timeit x_serial = serial_read(files)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 7.04 s per loop

%timeit x_parallel = parallel_read(files)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.56 s per loop

np.allclose(x_serial, x_parallel)
# True
```

It actually looks like a decent speedup. I am using two real and two hyper-threading cores.

---

To run and time everything at once, you can execute this script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

# some imports
import numpy as np
import glob
import sys
import multiprocessing
import os
import timeit

# creating some temporary data
tmp_dir = os.path.join('tmp', 'nptest')
if not os.path.exists(tmp_dir):
    os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
    for i in range(100):
        x = np.random.rand(10000, 50)
        file_path = os.path.join(tmp_dir, '%05d.npz' % i)
        np.savez_compressed(file_path, x=x)

def read_x(path):
    data = dict(np.load(path))
    return data['x']

def serial_read(files):
    x_list = list(map(read_x, files))
    return x_list

def parallel_read(files):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    x_list = pool.map(read_x, files)
    return x_list


files = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dir, '*.npz'))
#files = files[0:5] # to test on a subset of the npz files

# Timing:
timeit_runs = 5

timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: serial_read(files))
print('serial_read: {0:.4f} seconds averaged over {1} runs'
      .format(timer.timeit(number=timeit_runs) / timeit_runs,
      timeit_runs))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 7.04 s per loop

timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: parallel_read(files))
print('parallel_read: {0:.4f} seconds averaged over {1} runs'
      .format(timer.timeit(number=timeit_runs) / timeit_runs,
      timeit_runs))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.56 s per loop

# Examples of use:
x = serial_read(files)
print('len(x): {0}'.format(len(x))) # len(x): 100
print('len(x[0]): {0}'.format(len(x[0]))) # len(x[0]): 10000
print('len(x[0][0]): {0}'.format(len(x[0][0]))) # len(x[0]): 10000
print('x[0][0]: {0}'.format(x[0][0])) # len(x[0]): 10000
print('x[0].nbytes: {0} MB'.format(x[0].nbytes / 1e6)) # 4.0 MB
```

Comment: Yes, if the process is IO bound then multiprocessing will improve things.  (Minor detail, OP inquired about multithreading.)  But the OP said the process was CPU bound, so the overhead of managing multiple processes could actually hurt performance.