# Python speed up random disk read on HDD

Tags: python, io

i have a large set of files (each ~100kb) sitting on my HDD.
For each step of my algorithm, i need to **randomly** select and read in about 1000 files.
I use python and numpy.load to do this, and it is slow as heck.

How can i speed this up?
My intuition is that (except for bying a SSD), i could schedule all reads at once, and let the OS find an order which minimizes seek time. However, i'm not sure how to implement this in python.

- maybe spwan 1000 threads, each of which performs a read?
- is there asynchronous numpy.load or equivalent?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Creating 1000 threads probably won't help. For one thing, I doubt you have 1000 cores/cpus so the threads will end up waiting for cpu access a lot. Plus creating each thread has some overhead. The disk IO is the main issue. Disks are slow. Do you need all 1000 files immediately? Can you create a thread to load the files in the background while you process already loaded ones? Or maybe move the contents of the files to a database and just pull from the DB as needed? I'm not a numpy user - maybe it has a better solution.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is possible. How big is your set? If it is not several gigabytes, I would recommend loading everything into RAM (huge time cost at the beginning but you would avoid repeated reading of the files) and then just do the random selection there. For simple asynchronous reading, you can use joblib (https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) but I am unsure whether it will lead to speed ups.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! Unfortunately, the RAM is not big enough to hold all data (>500GB). And i already prefetch / hide the data I/O as much as possible (using pytorch.DataSet).
From my understanding, it should be possible to give the OS a list of files i want to load, and the OS 'figures' out a way to load them in the best possible order. That's what disk schedulers are for, right?  -->> @VladimírKunc I'll look into your joblib link, thanks!

Comment: Are you selecting the files for every step by querying the disk? If yes, you can make a list of file paths in the disk, and then just index it with random 1000 numbers to get the files required for every step. This will give you a little speed up. In addition to this, you can use multi threading to load the files, example, load the first 500 from one thread and load the remaining 500 from another thread. Increase the number of threads as you like

Comment: @S4rt-H4K i have a list of file paths in memory, from which i randomly sample N items.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, check my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example of the simple approach from my comment:

```
from threading import Thread
import timeit
arr=[]
def populate(content):
    for i in content:
        arr.append(i)
content1=[i for i in range(1,10000000)]
content2=[i for i in range(10000000,20000001)]

thread1=Thread(target=populate,kwargs={'content':content1})
thread2=Thread(target=populate,kwargs={'content':content2})

start = timeit.default_timer()
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
stop = timeit.default_timer()

print("time taken:",stop-start)
```

It took 3.546857 seconds with threads and 4.7215586 seconds without threads

So, there is a little speed up. You can add more threads to your problem and the times should improve further.

In your case, you will be loading a fraction of selected 1000 files with np.load and then appending this data to your main array

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write some code!
However, i'm note sure how this relates to my question, since you're doing all operations in memory - there is no disk I/O involved. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Oh yeah, it doesn't involve any i/o. Sorry I forgot that the problem has disk i/o involved. You can try using the solution in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328085/loading-several-npz-files-in-a-multithreadedly

Comment: also check disk %util in iostat, should be 100% for disk bottleneck